# replace a string with other string in the same line

Tags: string, text, replace, line, vi

Vi editor

Input file text format:

```
'': hello.Code1
'': hello.Code2
'': hello.Code3
```

Required output text format:

```
'Code1': hello.Code1
'Code2': hello.Code2
'Code3': hello.Code3
```

Idea is I have to copy all the values after "." to the single quotes ''. I can use Vi or SED etc. Linux based. or MAC based. 
I have more that 2000 lines in the text file
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a macro in vim. Something like:

```
/\.^Mly$?'^MPj0
```

Assuming you're at the start of the first line. Start recording. To record into the `q` register, hit `qq` and then:

i) Search for the dot

```
/\.^M
```

ii) Go one character to the right, and yank to the end of the line

```
ly$
```

iii) Reverse search the quote: `'`

```
?'^M
```

iv) Paste the content and go down a line and move to the start.

```
Pj0
```

You can then just repeat the action. Assuming you recorded it in the `q` register:

```
2@q
```

(Note: `^M` is `<Enter>`)

[image: Action Gif]

Comment: I have 2000 lines to replace.

Comment: Well, assuming it's structured similarly, you can just do `2000@q`.

Comment: it is not working for me . E486: Pattern not found: .^Mly$?'^MPj0

Comment: Did you record it properly? Staying at the start of the line and then hitting `qq` to start the recording.

Comment: You are pasting it all and hitting enter. You need to go about it step by step. 
Firstly, go to the start of the first line, hit `qq` to start recording. (It should say "recording") down below. And then type `/\.` and hit enter. You should be at the dot character now. 

Hit `l` so you are one character to the right.... and so on. 

When you have done it all, press `q` to stop the recording.

Comment: After recording , how do I tell it to repeat for n number of times

Comment: `n@q` Where `n` is the number of times you want it to repeat. I attached a demo.

Comment: Super. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This can be done quite simply with a substitute command and capturing groups. Try the following regex:

```
:%s/''\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/'\2'\1.\2
```

This says, *Search for quotes `''`, followed by anything captured into group 1 `\(.*\)`, followed by a literal dot `\.`, followed by anything captured into group 2 `\(.*\)`*. This will put

```
: hello
```

Into group 1, and

```
CodeN
```

into group 2. So then we replace it with *group 2 in quotes `'\2'` followed by group 1 `\1`, followed by a dot `\.` and group 2 again `\2`*.

If you put `\v` at the beginning of the regex, you can get rid of a lot of the backslashes and make it more readable:

```
:%s/\v''(.*)\.(.*)/'\2'\1.\2
```

---

You could also do this with a `%normal` command. That makes a set of keystrokes be applied to every line in the buffer. I would try this:

```
:%norm f.ly$0p
```

This says, *On every line, do the following keystrokes `:%norm` Move forward to a '.' `f.`, move one character to the right `l`, yank everything to the end of this line `y$`, move to the beginning of this line `0`, and paste what we just yanked `p`*

Comment: nothing wrong with the macro solution, but the macro might be quite slow given the 2000+ lines